# Use MITM Proxy to forward all HTTPS requests to local Express.js app

Tags: node.js, express, https, mitmproxy

I have an Express.js app running on a server. On this same server I'd like to setup a MITM proxy that sends all https requests to my Express.js app. The Express.js app is publicly available via https using NGINX reverse proxy. So directing traffic via localhost or via public https url is fine.

This Express.js app just returns a single html file, so I'd also be okay if the MITM proxy didn't need Express at all and just returned the html file.

I was hoping to use the following package since I'm familiar with Node.js, but I'm not sure how to achieve the desired result. https://github.com/joeferner/node-http-mitm-proxy

I'm also open to other solutions if applicable. Thanks!

For this example below, let's just assume my Express.js app returns a simple 'hello world' message.

Example:

- Set proxy for application to myserver.com:5555
- In application, make request to https://google.com
- Proxy server either re-routes traffic to Express.js or returns 'hello world'
- Application sees url as https://google.com but sees response of 'hello world'

I understand that the certificates will not match but I can ignore that in my application.

Comment: You could also use nginx to serve the html file. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/

Comment: Thanks @Molda the problem is that I need the server to handle a forward proxy request and not just a regular http request.

Comment: @yourfavorite Did you find any luck with this?